# Specify specific fields to audit in grails audit logging plugin

Tags: grails, plugins, audit

I am using the http://grails.org/plugin/audit-logging plugin and am only interested in auditing a single field in a large domain class.  I could specify a lengthy 'ignore' list, but ideally I want to specify the whitelist of fields instead, so that if new fields are added, it is not necessary to maintain the ignore list to avoid them getting automatically audited which could be a performance risk.

Is this possible?  I didn't see mention of it in the docs for the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do this using the event handlers only instead of the standard audit logging.  You would set auditing like this

```
static auditable = [handlersOnly: true]
```

You could create a white list

```
def whiteList = ['name','age',...]
```

Then create on* events to handle a save, delete or change event and iterate through the white list to look up that key in the old and new map:

```
def onChange = {oldMap, newMap ->
    whiteList.each{propName->
       if(oldMap[propName] != newMap[propName]) {
         //
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was able to modify the audit logging source to handle this with an 'only' list that is used like the 'ignore' list.  If you'd like I can post what I did - it works for me (and I may start using it for my projects) but it's not cleaned up.  For example it looks at the 'ignore' list and removes those items, then takes the 'only' list and removes the items not in that list so it is a bit redundant.